# How to code a program in prolog based like this

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to code a program in prolog that uses only the letters {a,b,c} and takes l number of a, m number of b and n number of c. But it has to be in the order a,b,c. Example : [a,b,c] is true, [a,a,b,b,c] is true, [a,b] is true, [a] is true, [b] is true, [c] is true,[a,c] is true, [b,c] is true, [a,a,a,b,b] is true. But [b,a,c] is false, [c,b] is also false and same goes for [b,b,b,c,c,c,a]. Because the order is wrong.
Here is what I tried to do but it doesn't do exactly what I want :

```
langageAB([b]).

langageAB([b | S]):-
    langageAB(S).

langageAC([c]).

langageAC([c | S]):-
    langageAC(S).

langage7([a, b, c]).

langage7([a | S]):-
    langage7(S).

langage7([a |S]):-
    langageAB(S).

langage7([b | S]):-
    langage7(S).

langage7([b | S]):-
    langageAC(S).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by defining a predicate to create a *difference list* containing zero or more elements equal to `X`. With this data structure, concatenation of new elements can be done in constant time. In the following definition, the *difference list* is represented by the pair composed by the second and third arguments of the predicate `langage_x/3`.

```
langage_x(_, S, S).
langage_x(X, [X|S], T) :-
    langage_x(X, S, T).
```

Example:

```
?- langage_x(a, A, B).
A = B ;
A = [a|B] ;
A = [a, a|B] ;
A = [a, a, a|B] .

?- langage_x(a, A, []).
A = [] ;
A = [a] ;
A = [a, a] ;
A = [a, a, a] .
```

Note that if `A = [a,a,a|B]`, for example, then the difference list `A-B` represents the list `[a,a,a]`. Also, an instantiation of variable `B` automatically extends the represented list (or closes it, if `B` is instantiated with `[]`).

Afterward, you can define the predicate `langage7/1` as follows:

```
langage7(A) :-
    langage_x(a, A, B),
    langage_x(b, B, C),
    langage_x(c, C, []). % this last goal closes the list!
```

To check if a sequence belongs to the language, you can ask:

```
?- langage7([a,a,b,c,c,c]).
true .

?- langage7([a,a,c,c]).
true .

?- langage7([a,b,a,c,c]).
false.
```

To generate all sequences of the language, you can ask:

```
?- length(L, _), langage7(L).
L = [] ;
L = [c] ;
L = [b] ;
L = [a] ;
L = [c, c] ;
L = [b, c] ;
L = [b, b] ;
L = [a, c] ;
L = [a, b] ;
L = [a, a] ;
L = [c, c, c] ;
...
```